# How to list items as groups in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

Is it possible to to set QListWidget items in groups.

For example if i am adding the content of a folder to listwidget. i want to show all folders in folders group and files in files group. Like in the image below.

[image]

Is it possible.

Answer (score 5):

Create for each group a list with all items, sort the list by an arbitrary property  and add  the item groups in desired order to listwidget. Between or in front of the groups a delimiter or title can be added, the groups can get different styles.

e.g. your files/folders groups:

```
    files.sort()            # list of files
    folders.sort()          # list of folders

    for f in folders:
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon1.xpm'))
        item.setText(f)
        # set further properties  like font, background ...
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()          # delimiter
    item.setText('-----------------------')
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)        # item should not be selectable
    self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    for f in files:
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setIcon(QtGui.Qicon('icon2.xpm'))
        item.setText(f)
        # set further properties   like font, background ...  
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

for files and folders QTreeView/QFileSystemModel might be another solution.

using QTableWidget in a corresponding way items can be grouped in rows:
[image: items grouped in rows]